# Ubuntu WSL Ansible - user@localhost Permission denied(publickey,password)

Tags: ansible

I am using ubuntu WSL as a controller for ansible.
Trying to install python dependencies in localhost and then launch an ec2 instance
But failing due to below error:
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: kevin@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password)."

**Things I did to fix:**
1.Did ssh-keygen
2.Generating public/private rsa key pair.
3.Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa):
4.Finally $ cat ~/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

**Things Worked:**

1.ssh localhost is working for kevin@localhost

2.First I use an existing RHEL ec2 instance with pem file,with this i can run my tasks and launch instances

**Things Not Working:**

**--2 Type of errors--**

Playbook Task having same issue

1. **failed: [localhost] (item=webserverA)** =>

   {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "webserverA", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: kevin@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}
   fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "All items completed", "results": [{"ansible_loop_var": "item", "item": "webserverA", "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: kevin@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}]}
2. <127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER:

   kevin
   <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~kevin && sleep 0'
   <127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "`echo /home/kevin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1590382761.4873009-58188090245831`" && echo ansible-tmp-1590382761.4873009-58188090245831="`echo /home/kevin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1590382761.4873009-58188090245831`" ) && sleep 0'

   "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"`echo /home/kevin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1590382762.0043557-97164890408687`\" && echo ansible-tmp-1590382762.0043557-97164890408687=\"`echo /home/kevin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1590382762.0043557-97164890408687`\" ), exited with result 1, stdout output: ansible-tmp-1590382762.0043557-97164890408687=/home/kevin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1590382762.0043557-97164890408687\n",

**Clarification:**
1.In ansible.cfg file which key should be given for private_key_file .pem file or id_rsa
My understanding is to ssh localhost we need id_rsa and to ssh ec2 instance we need .pem file
So kindly support on to fix issue 1

2.For issue 2 I tried to give remote_tmp path in ansible.cfg and connection=local but not worked

**Inventory file:**

## hosts-dev

```
[webservers]
localhost ansible_user=kevin

**Play.yml**
- name: Creates the ec2 instances
    hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: no
    roles:
      - python
    tasks:  
      - name: Launch an EC2 Instance
        ec2_instance: 
//Using the access keys here
```

**Verbose output:**

```
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: kevin
<localhost> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o 'IdentityFile="/home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="kevin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/kevin/.ansible/cp/9faa73ac6e localhost '/bin/sh 
-c '"'"'echo ~kevin && sleep 0'"'"''
<localhost> (255, b'', b'kevin@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).\r\n')
<localhost> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: kevin
<localhost> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30m -o 'IdentityFile="/home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="kevin"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/kevin/.ansible/cp/9faa73ac6e localhost '/bin/sh 
-c '"'"'echo ~kevin && sleep 0'"'"''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .pem you get from Amazon is a private key as is id_rsa.

Validate what your Ansible should be doing by performing ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa kevin@localhost.

If that works you fundamentally have all the pieces required and should look at your ansible configuration to determine.

If you cannot perform the following validations:

- Do you have permissions to access the key? It should be chmod 400 with the owner as the user that you run Ansible as.
- Is that the correct user on that server?
- Adding -v to the end will provide more verbose debug, you can keep appending another v (i.e. -vv or -vvv) to get even more verbose debug upto 4 vs.

Your ansible.cfg should look like this

```
[defaults]
private_key_file = /home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Yes I can able to perform ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa kevin@localhost.

Comment: Right, can you paste more examples of your configuration

Comment: My Playbook as a play 1.Hosts as Localhost which needs to run a python role and launch an ec2 instance .In ansible.cfg private_key_file = /home/kevin/.ssh/id_rsa  and chmod 400 permission is given for user "kevin"

Comment: Hi, can you verify the ansible.cfg file looks exactly like I have added to my answer

Comment: Yes I verified my ansible.cfg with yours,it is same.kindly check my verbose output

Comment: Just to confirm theres no password on that id_Rsa file?

Comment: id_rsa file is in readonly mode when I open for user kevin using vim editor.It has openssh private key

Comment: I got error 2 so i did a ubuntu full upgrade and issues solved i can launch instance from localhost  `wget https://launchpad.net/~rafaeldtinoco/+archive/ubuntu/lp1871129/+files/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg --install libc6_2.31-0ubuntu8+lp1871129~1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-mark hold libc6

sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt full-upgrade `